# QGIS: Changing labeling color within label

Tags: qgis, labeling, color, change

I have a point layer in QGIS that looks like the following picture:

[image: label on QGIS canvas]

Content of the `Dicke Auf` field :

```
BS 4/ DPM 4
Ansatzhöhe: 275.96
UK Auffüllung: 274.71
Dicke Auffüllung: 1.3
OK Sand: 274.62
Grundwasser: 271,26
```

Now I'd like to change the color of the different labels individually (e.g. OK Sand = red, Grundwasser = blue). Is that possible?

I already tried the editor, but I only managed to change the entire label:

```sql
if ("Dicke Auf"  >=  '0,5','cyan','red')
```

Comment: What software is this? QGIS? Some ESRI product? Can you add a tag for it and maybe mention in the question?

Comment: Thank you, how dumb to forget that. I edited the question and the tags, i work with QGis.

Comment: Be also sure to include the QGIS version you use. Otherwise, we assume you use the most recent (current) version. If you use an older version, functionalities may not be available.

Answer (score 3):

Labeling in different colors is possible with [html-formatted labels](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#text-tab), introduced [in QGIS 3.28](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog328/index.html#feature-add-support-for-html-bold-italic-font-size-and-font-family-to-labelling). See [here for some use cases](https://north-road.com/2022/09/09/mixed-format-labels-in-qgis-coming-soon/).

Check the box `Allow html formatting` in the `Text` tab of label settings. Then insert a html code in the value field. Use [`format()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format) function, define the styles you want using placeholders like `%1`, then add the text content you want to have formatted this way.

Here is an example of the syntax to use to have the first line with the content of `field_1` in blue, on the next line `field_2` in red:

```
format(
  '<span style="color:blue"> <p> %1 </p> </span> <br>
   <span style="color:red"> %2 </span>',
  field_1,
  field_2
)
```

or, with the same result, simply concatenating the different elements:

```
'<span style="color:blue"><p>'  ||  field_1  || '</p></span>'  || 
'<span style="color:red">'  ||  field_2  || '</span><br>'
```

[image]

You can also mix this to get different font sizes, bold/strong, italic etc. like this:

```
'<span style="color:blue"><p style="font-size: 40pt"; ><strong>'  ||  field_1  || '</strong></p></span>'  || 
'<span style="color:red"><p style="font-size: 30pt"><i>'  ||  field_2  || '</i></p></span>'  || 
'<span style="color:green"><p style="font-size: 20pt">'  ||  field3 || '</p></span>'
```

[image]